# Show one element/div at a time from list

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a single code hide all elements with the same class but show the one element by ID. The way it's implemented right now it just stacks the divs on top of each other. Anyway to show just one div at a time?

```
<script>
function CurtindoAlesadoDesktop() {
  var x = document.getElementById("curtindo-a-vida-alesado");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
</script>
```

Link in use: maninhoflix.com.br (desktop only)

Comment: What determins which element should be visible?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I use css to hide the divs. They are set as display: none; and then it changes to block once I click a button to activate this js code

Comment: I think the question from icecub was, what is the logic or rule to show/hide the divs.  Your question seems incomplete from a fresh pair of eyes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like the following?

```
function showIdAndHideOthers(idToShow) {
  const elementsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName('class-to-hide');
  const elementToShow = document.getElementById(idToShow);
  for (const el of elementsToHide) {
    el.style.display = 'none';
  }
  elementToShow.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Alternatively, you could use two CSS classes, one which hides all elements by default, and another which shows the active element. Then, you can keep track of the most recently shown element and simply add/remove a class.

For example (CSS):

```
.thing {
  display: none;
}

.thing.selected {
  display: block;
}
```

JS:

```
let lastElement;
function showIdAndHideOthers(idToShow) {
  const elementToShow = document.getElementById(idToShow);
  if (lastElement != null) {
    lastElement.classList.remove('selected');
  }
  elementToShow.classList.add('selected');
  lastElement = elementToShow;
}
```

EDIT: Example for the second: https://codepen.io/minism/pen/GRgGdPg

Comment: i'd be careful using `.active` as a classname. there's also [a pseudo-class called `:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) that could cause confusion for folks reading this code down the line.

Comment: I wasn't able to make this code work. Do I have to use both js codes in order for the second method to work?

Comment: Here's a fully functional example: https://codepen.io/minism/pen/GRgGdPg

Comment: Thank you very much! This is it!